# Using Git for content versioning on a Mid-Sized News Site

Tags: git, media

I am working on a mid-sized news site, we expect to generate from 20 to 40 new articles per day, extracted from 3rd party sources and been generated by our 3 people content team.

The site pages will be generated from markdown files using a custom static site generator.

We are evaluating the use of a git based workflow to versioning the site content (markdown files) and fire the site builds but these are our main concerns:

- We don't want authors to download the whole site content locally. Because they are only interested on articles they work.
- Single file versioning is a key feature for us, but having snapshots of the hole site content isn't a priority.

Does Git cover this requirements? is there another tool that fits better?

Thanks!

Comment: Does any of this content include _binary_ data, such as images?  Git doesn't do so well with binary, especially large binary files.

Comment: More info would be useful. For example , is it a known CMS like Wordpress or Joomla? Or it is a custom application. How the content is stored? For example if it is a wordpress you can utilize backup plugins for Wordpress that do the job. Do you need versioning of every article? (WP has it naively) or you need backup? Then you dont need GIT but backup....

Comment: For example ta ke alook at VersionPress if it is a Wordpress site: https://versionpress.net/

Comment: Thanks Tim! The versioned content are markdown files. The media files will be stored on S3 and are not going to be versioned.

Comment: Thanks @e4rthdog! the site will be generated using a custom static site generator. We need at least content backups, but per article versioning is prefered.

Comment: Git is per-repository versioning, either you version everything together or you create many small repositories. I would say git is not the best tool you should use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We don't want authors to download the whole site content locally. Because they are only interested on articles they work.

Since git versions the whole project, putting the whole site into one repository does not help you with this requirement.

> Single file versioning is a key feature for us, but having snapshots of the hole site content isn't a priority.

You may have a single directory (and git repository) per article and do your work there. Or per day, per week, per issue, you name it. But then you have to manage a lot of repositories.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you find a way to export *ALL* your content in a specific place and use GIT on that directory.

For example you could export all the articles with a specific file naming convention that will not change so GIT can keep versions of your file and have different commits per same file.

Moreover you should have a separate procedure for application+database backup.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. The site generator reads the markdown files from a source folder that is structured as follows: `/_source/year/month/day/<article_slug.md>. I think using git on it will have the limitations described by Stefan. As you suggested we are going to handle the backups separately. The site theme and front dynamic parts will be versioned using git and the database in our case only for the site comments and user profiles will have separated backups.